# Зависимость заголовочных файлов друг от друга

Tags: c++

`<algorithm>` включает в себя `<limits>` или почему компилируется?

```
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::numeric_limits<__int64>::min();
}
```

Comment: Стандарт, полагаю, этого не предписывает, но и не запрещает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Постараюсь более развернуто ответить о том, что уже было сказано в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500615/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-algorithm#comment596890_500615) к вопросу.

Действительно, Стандарт языка не регламентирует какие заголовочные файлы могут включать другие. При этом, в силу обширности библиотеки, наличия взаимосвязей между отдельными компонентами, конечно же, не избежать.

Однако, стоит иметь в виду, что каждой функции, переменной и т.д. (в общем, любому имени) сопоставлен некоторый заголовочный файл (или даже несколько).
Именно этот заголовочный файл и следует подключать через `#include` во избежании появления ошибок компиляции при переносе кода на другой компилятор, или даже другую версию того же компилятора.

Например, следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<void(void)> f;
}
```

компилируется в [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/B9sP9948WAYn0i8A), но не компилируется в [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tC2BLOxG1dijCkgW). Если же включить `<functional>` явно, код должен собираться в любом компиляторе. В частности, он начинает собираться в [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/b2DANkjItSZf7LSJ).

Comment: Особенно этим грешит MSVC  — подключил один заголовок, получил целый ворох, а потом начинается веселье, когда надо под Linux/OS X код собирать...

Comment: @ixSci подключить нужные хидеры не так уж и сложно потом. Но правильнее, конечно, это делать сразу. Сложнее, если вдруг окажется важен _порядок_ их подключения.