# подключение map, pair

Tags: c++

Для подключения `map` и `pair` нужно писать

```
#include <map>
```

или

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
```

?

Comment: Мам использует пару, следовательно, она там есть. А вообще, можно нагуглить легко или просто попробовать.

Comment: @AivanF. просто попробовать - очень плохой вариант (хотя я часто так делаю). Компиляторы очень вольно трактуют стандарт, и при переходе на другой компилятор (или даже при автоматическом обновлении текущего) всё может сломаться

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зависимость заголовочных файлов друг от друга](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500615/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0)

Comment: @egor - правильно поступать так, как отвечено в том вопросе - хотите максимально переносимый код - тащите все заголовки с собой.

Answer (score 1):

Стандарт языка C++ не регламентирует того, как связаны между собой заголовочные файлы. Для получения максимально переносимого между компиляторами текста программы, необходимо отыскивать заголовок с явным определением нужного типа (например, на сайте http://www.cppreference.com) и включать его.

Answer (score 0):

`map` вполне хватает,тут ссылка на описание `map` [СppReference Map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/), как видим `pair` уже является частью библиотеки `map`.

Если интересно, тут [stl_map.h](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_map.h) имплементация stl::map